# How to render the vue template into the django views?

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, django-rest-framework, django-views

Firstly I am creating the question and answer type app which the user creates questions. If the user added the same question which is present in the django API then I need to through an error on the template. So this app I used vuejs and django, DRF and webpack. Now I want to compare the questions present in the DB and user ready to push question content.

#1. If this is not correct process How can I compare in the vuejs script.
#2. How can we render the vuejs template into the django views

```
 return render('request' , QuestionEditor.vue')
```

Is it the correct way to render the template of vue into the django?

```
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Question

def content(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('content')

        if Question.objects.filter(content=content).exists():
            messages.warning(request, 'Question already exists')
            return redirect('ask') # ask is nothing but name in the vuejs router file
    else:
        question = Question(content=content)
        question.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Question has been added')
        return redirect('/')
return render(request, '../views/QuestionEditor.vue')
```

Comment: check https://github.com/JuliRash/Django-Vue-SPA

Comment: Frontend is different and backend is differenet so I want to connect the vuejs template in the  django views? But I did not get the answer from the above github link @Spruce